# Open-source tool for monitoring network requests within python-selenium tests (Alternative for browsermob-proxy)

Tags: open-source, python, software-testing

I am looking for an alternative for [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) (for automated testing), as this JAVA project is not maintained anymore, and does not work in various cases.

I am looking either for a very similar project/tool being currently maintained (in any language) OR a very similar project/tool coded in python (maintained or not maintained).

**Important**: The tool must create a HAR file (just like browsermob-proxy)